# std::variant<Ts...> as last argument of template function taking multiple variadic arguments

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, c++20, std-variant

I have the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <variant>

template <class... Ts>
struct overloaded : Ts...
{
    using Ts::operator()...;
};
template <class... Ts>
overloaded(Ts...) -> overloaded<Ts...>;

template<typename... Fns, typename... Ts>
void xvisit(std::variant<Ts...> var, const Fns... fns ){
    std::visit(overloaded{fns...}, var);
}
```

It seems to be working fine([godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/njb1cdnoo)), but I can not find a way to make the `std::variant<Ts...>` be the last argument of `xvisit`.

For example when I swap the order of arguments I get useless errors from both clang and gcc:

> note:   '<lambda(const string&)>' is not derived from
> 'std::variant<_Types ...>'
>
> note: candidate template ignored: could not match
> 'variant<type-parameter-0-1...>' against '(lambda at :23:17)'

[godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/Mj3EncbfM) with problematic xvisit2.

Can this be fixed, or am I hitting some language limitation?

note: I know `xvisit` should not be returning `void`, this is just an example.

Comment: Your parameter pack should be the last argument. You can't have any other arguments following parameter pack arguments. There should be a duplicate, I am 101% sure.

Comment: @nathan the problem is that says *why it doesn't work*, it doesn't answer *how to do it*.  Because it can be done, it just is a lot more work than you should put into it.  Honestly, if your really want trailing variant access, `xvisitor(fns...)(variant)` is probably a better choice (and has the cute syntax that matches `overloaded`).  Or even `overloaded{fns...}.visit(variants...)` to make it explicit.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont Are you talking about `Parameters after parameter pack in function [duplicate]` or `Variadic function template with pack expansion not in last parameter`?  In the latter you have an answer that is a work around.

Comment: @NathanOliver Ah, I ran into checkmark itis, where I stopped at the checkmark.  Yes, that is the kind of bad plan that answers the OP's question more literally.  :)

Comment: Thanks everybody, I know of this limitation, but I thought it only applies to template arguments, like <typename... Ts, typename U> is banned, not on the function argument order...